# Schedule Selenium Web driver Jar files from batch file of Window Scheduler

Tags: java, automation, selenium-webdriver

I use the following batch file to run jar file and it run successfully. But I want to schedule this program every day from Window Scheduler. I tried to put both selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar or all selenium jar files in my program of Eclipse, and it both failed. I inserted java and selenium path in environment variables. It seems like the port is just listened and nothing works.

Any idea for this? 
I appreciate for your suggestion and ideas.

```
@echo off
java -jar "C:\Tasks\autoscript.jar" %*
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set classpath in the batch file, may be it is not able to find the classpath.

I am using below technique it is working for me, i think it may help you:

Create an testng.xml file say name as testsuite.xml.

Now follow below 2 steps:

Step 1: Create an batch file for scheduler:

use below code - modify it and paste in notepad. save the notepad in working directory as"run.bat"

set ProjectPath=C:\Selenium\Selenium_tests\DemoProject 
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Lib*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testsuite.xml

a) First line is for setting project path
b) second line is for verifying that path is set or not.
c) third line is for setting claspath - lib folder contain all the jar file added to project build path
d) fourth line is for verifying whether classpath is set or not
e) fifth line is for executing xml file having details of all test.

Step 2: go to control panel > administrative tool >task scheduler and create a task which will trigger run.bat file at the time you want.

it will work.